# Generating a maven site including a Cobertura Report

Tags: java, maven-2, code-coverage, cobertura

I've got some projects that are already doing site generation via maven, and I want to integrate cobertura reports in them, but no maven goal I seem to run will generate a local preview for me to look at that includes the Cobertura reports in the site.  I want to be sure they're generating correctly before I commit the pom changes to the repo and have broken site generated.

Below is what I've added to the maven poms (parent and module), but the site I see when I run `mvn site:run` does not include the cobertura reports:

```
<project>
...
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <check>
                    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                    <regexes>
                        <regex>
                            <pattern>parent-package-name-here.*</pattern>
                            <branchRate>80</branchRate>
                            <lineRate>80</lineRate>
                        </regex>
                    </regexes>
                </check>
                <instrumentation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>parent-package-name-here/**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
...
</project>
```

What maven command should I use to generate the site with cobertura reports?  Or, what should I add (additionally) to get the site generation to include the cobertura reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

It seems there are a lot of bugs in the link generation within the maven site generation plugin.

The only way I've found to make maven generate a local copy of the site with working module links is to modify the `distributionManagement/site` tag to point to some local directory instead of the real-live deploy directory, then use `maven site:deploy`.

Every attempt to use `mvn site:stage` generates broken links.  Same goes for `mvn site:run`.

The report links work with `mvn site:run` / `mvn site:stage` but the links to modules do not.

Comment: You should file this as bugs in maven's bug tracker, otherwise it will not be worked on.

Answer (score 3):

Should do:

```
mvn site
```

To elaborate, running **mvn a:b** runs the goal b in plugin a.  Saying **mvn c** means to run the lifecycle phase c, which runs all of the bound goals in all of the phases up to c.  As a result, this will trigger a lot more things to happen (such as doing the necessary preparation to produce cobertura reports).

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn site
```

should do what you are looking for. You configure the plugin to run in the pre-site and site phases of the life cycle but your are then executing the site:run goal not site. We are doing similar things with clover (commercial coverage tool) and mvn site does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

site:stage module links don't work in my experience either for multi module builds but site:deploy does. Try this:

Use a property for the site URL in the parent pom, e.g. `${site.url}`. Then call this

```
mvn clean site site:deploy -Dsite.url=file://`pwd`/target/site-deployed
```

The `pwd` is a `-nix` command that will substitute the current directory. This is because the URL that you use must be absolute.

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
mvn site-deploy
```

This builds the site and deploys it (copies it to the place we have configured).

Comment: But I don't want to deploy it to its "production" location, I want a local preview first as this is still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn site:site` should produce what you are after, in the target directory, there will be a site directory containing all reports linked with an `index.html` in that directory.